# Compiler Depenedent Error with typedef

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, typedef, win64

I am trying to compile my project with different compilers. i have a stable compiled version of the project compiling without any error with the ARM 4.41 compiler. I want to compiler the exactly same source code with the ARM 5 compiler and the Win64 compiler. How ever without any change in the source code, just by switching the compiler from ARM 4.41 to ARM 5 && ARM 4.41 to Win64 i am getting the following error with the typedef's.

I am not able to figure it out, why does it behaves so..?

Header file with typedef's - a_stdtypes.h

```
#define _STD_TYPE_H
typedef unsigned char  bool; // Error #84: invalid combination of type specifiers
typedef unsigned char  bit8;
typedef unsigned short bit16;
typedef unsigned long  bit32;
```

Comment: isn't `bool` primitive type of c++?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't legal C++ code. `bool` is a reserved keyword of the language - a type. You cannot redefine its meaning. It would be legal C code, though.

Comment: yes...
i agree, but what i am trying to resolve is, the error is reported with change in compiler. Irrespective of the compiler the code remains the same.

Do you have any ideas to debug or anything which differentiate.

Comment: Either you're compiling C code as C++ code now (perhaps the compiler uses a different default language in the new version), or the compiler's support for C++ improved with the version change, so it's now correctly rejecting invalid code. You'll have to consult the compiler's documentation, particularly "what's new in 5".

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was wrote because someone want to define bool for C, then someone else want to use it from C++.

a neater solution is to use cplusplus macro, like this:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef unsigned char  bool;
#endif
typedef unsigned char  bit8;
typedef unsigned short bit16;
typedef unsigned long  bit32;
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon -- and I'd argue that a better definition is `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`. Also, for C99 the `typedef` can be replaced with `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: you are right for all your comments, but I tried not to change his code too much. and I'm not missing semicolon anymore... :)